How to fetch the current list of SPL tokens?
I'm looking to programmatically fetch the (full) official list of SPL tokens so that I can do a fuzzy search on ticker symbols. For a given input string, I would like to get a dictionary of all token strings with a fuzzy match, and their associated contract addresses.
Something like this:

Ideally I would do this in Python, but I will make any language work!

The United Token List API by SolFlare also provides token information. They have a JS SDK at https://github.com/solflare-wallet/utl-sdk

Have you checked out the Jupiter list API
Here's a link to the docs
https://station.jup.ag/docs/token-list/token-list-api#:~:text=The%20Jupiter%20Token%20List%20API,safer%20for%20users%20and%20developers.
